# How dividing values in cell automatically

Tags: vba, excel

Well I have a set of cells with certain values (in minutes) and I would like to transform them to hours, the issue is that these values are constantly updated, so I need the last row of the column to be variant.

I wrote this code, but the problem is with xldown there seems to be something that I am omitting:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheets1").Range("C3").End(xlDown).Select
For Each c In rng
    c.Value = c.Value / 60
Next
```

So the basic idea is that can capture the last value of C and divide it by 60.

Any suggestion/ideas are welcome.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Since you are setting the range to a variable, you don't need the `.Select` on the end of the code line. Also, that will only give the last cell with data in the column.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim rng As Range, c As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheets1")
    'edit: switch to xlUp
    Set rng = .Range(.Range("C3"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
end with

For Each c In rng.Cells
    'edit: check cell has a value...
    If Len(c.value) > 0 Then c.Value = c.Value / 60
Next
```

Comment: the problem with this is that having only one cell value in some column example "D3" filled with 0 to all of the below. Any ideas to solve it?

Comment: Edited version is a bit more robust